# Mutex on a process android

Tags: android

Recently I have migrated to Firebase and i want to use the crashes report.
It is stated that if I have a class extending Application class They may be Concurrency Issues and this class must be multi-process safe.
This is my class.

```
public class InnolertApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        synchronized (InnolertApplication.class) {
            Dexter.initialize(getApplicationContext());
        }
    }
}
```

I thought about Semaphores to protect the Initialization ,but from the Docs i understand that this is used in android only for threads.

this is the reference :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#deobfuscate_proguard_labels

Crash Reporting creates a separate background process to upload crash info. If your app extends the Android Application class, you must ensure it is multi-process safe. Otherwise, it may cause concurrency issues. When an app extends an Application object, this object gets instantiated for each process in a multi-process app.

Comment: 1. Where is it stated there may be concurrency issues? 2. What is your question?

Comment: see my edit @cyroxis

Comment: Again what is your question?

Comment: What is the right way in android to do this,I mean preventing this line to execute many times :            Dexter.initialize(getApplicationContext());

Comment: The synchronization will not matter, a separate processes do not have shared memory. You need to determine if Dexter is safe to use in a multi process environment. If not you can not use Dexter and the crash reporting.

Comment: ok i will verify it thank you